# Android Phone stopped notifiying about usb connection with PC

Tags: android, connection, usb, adb, mount

I've a Samsung Galaxy S2 device which I had been using for Android development through adb for almost two month. A few days ago it just stoppt detecting the usb connection with my Thinkpad T420. Here are the odd facts:

- problem appears only on this single laptop but across operating systems (multi-boot): windows 7, fedora 15, ubuntu 11.04; they all worked fine before
- the device in question charges but does not show the "usb connected" notification
- there are no udev events at all (checked with shell command 'udevadm monitor')
- an other Samsung Galaxy S2 and other usb devices are working fine with the same cable on the same usb-port
- the device in question works as expected with other computers (OSX and Ubuntu), eg. shows the 'usb connected' notification and can be mounted or used with adb

Are there other options then to try a full factory reset?

Comment: I'd like to see the answer to this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By pure luck I plugged the cable into the device while the Android OS was switching to offline mode (selected from the menu which appears when long-pressing the power button). That did the trick!

After some experiments I can verify using the transitions between offline and online mode to plug the cable into the PC is a workaround -- not a fix to the problem.